# php writing a onkeyup= function

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am writing a php script which generates html with a javascript onkeyup event, as such:

```
// generate the function text
            $fn_text = "checkContentQuizAnswer(\"#".$var_name."\",\"".$equation_solutions_array[0][0]."\",\"{'incorrect_values':[";     
                for($r=1;$r<count($equation_solutions_array);$r++) {
                    // THIS ISNT WORKING CORRECTLY, NEED A BETTER WAY TO PASS INCORRECT INFO
                    $fn_text .= "{'equation':'".$equation_solutions_array[$r][0]."','message':'".$equation_solutions_array[$r][1]."'}";
                    if(($r+1)<count($equation_solutions_array)) {
                        $fn_text .= ",";
                    }
                }
            $fn_text .= "]}\")";
```

However this isnt working... the code it generates looks something like this:

```
onkeyup="checkContentQuizAnswer("#theonlyvariable","27.62*5","{'incorrect_values':[{'equation':'27.62+5','message':'you added 5'},{'equation':'27.62-5','message':'you subtracted 5'}]}")"
```

however, it hasn't been working... the errors have included complaints about missing }'s, MathJax (an eval() style library) is undefined.

Im sure that it is how I am parsing the onkeyup part of the  tag but i cant get the combination/syntax correct.

Can anybody see a glaring problem? :S

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Look at the code highlighting of the generated code, and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Even the SO syntax highlighting shows you the problem

Comment: Use single quote outside and double quotes inside. make sure you have escaped quotes properly.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, however checkContentQuizAnswer(\"#theonlyvariable\",\"21.3*5\",\"{\'incorrect_values\':[{\'equation\':\'21.3+5\',\'message\':\'you added 5\'},{\'equation\':\'21.3-5\',\'message\':\'you subtracted 5\'}]}\")" give me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL - with line number 1 as the problem (its a blank line).

Answer (score 0):

Although you are escaping the quotes in the PHP file, the quotes in the javascript parser are not being escaped. Change the quotes inside the onKeyUp to single quotes to fix this. You will also need to escape the quotes in the JSON as well - the `json_encode()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) can help with that. You need to output something like:

```
onkeyup="checkContentQuizAnswer('#theonlyvariable','27.62*5','{\'incorrect_values\':[{\'equation\':\'27.62+5\',\'message\':\'you added 5\'},{\'equation\':\'27.62-5\',\'message\':\'you subtracted 5\'}]}')"
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but when I get:

    checkContentQuizAnswer('#theonlyvariable','36.53*5','{\'incorrect_values\':[{\'equation\':\'36.53+5\',\'message\':\'you added 5\'},{\'equation\':\'36.53-5\',\'message\':\'you subtracted 5\'}]}")"

I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL - Unfortunatele it gives me no indication of where this occurs and just refers me to line 1 of the HTML :S